# I have tests that fail when run together but pass when run individually

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

This is the primary function, I have noticed when I place the passwordConditions obj inside the passwordIsValid function all the tests pass.

```
    function passwordIsValid(password) {
          if (password.length == 0) {
            throw errorMessages.passwordNotFound;
          }
          if (password.length < 9) {
            throw errorMessages.invalidLength;
          }
           for (const condition in passwordConditions) {
             if (!passwordConditions[condition].test(password)) {
               throw errorMessages[condition]();
             }
           }
        
          return true;
        }
```

Helper functions

```
   const passwordConditions = {
             "lowercase letter": /[a-z]/g,
             "uppercase letter": /[A-Z]/g,
             "digit ": /[0-9]/g,
             "special character": /[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/g,
             "whitespace character": /\s/g,
           };

    const errorMessages = {
      passwordNotFound: "password should exist",
      invalidLength: "password should be longer than 8 characters",

      "lowercase letter": () =>
        `password should have at least one lowercase letter`,

      "uppercase letter": () =>
        `password should have at least one uppercase letter`,

      "digit ": () => `password should have at least one digit `,

      "special character": () =>
        `password should have at least one special character`,

      "whitespace character": () =>
        `password should have at least one whitespace character`,

      errorType: () => Object.keys(passwordConditions),
      errorRegex: () => Object.values(passwordConditions),
    };
```

These are the tests

```
    describe("passwordChecker.js", () => {
      describe("passwordIsValid", () => {
        it("should return true", () => {
          expect(passwordIsValid("p@s5 Words")).toBe(true);
        });
        it("should return password should exist", () => {
          expect(function () {
            passwordIsValid("");
          }).toThrow(errorMessages.passwordNotFound);
        });
        it("should return password should be longer than 8 characters", () => {
          expect(function () {
            passwordIsValid("P@s5 ");
          }).toThrow(errorMessages.invalidLength);
        });
        it("should return password should have at least one lowercase letter", () => {
          expect(function () {
            passwordIsValid("P@S5 WORDS");
          }).toThrow(errorMessages["lowercase letter"]());
        });
        it("should return password should have at least one uppercase letter", () => {
          expect(function () {
            passwordIsValid("p@s5 words");
          }).toThrow(errorMessages["uppercase letter"]());
        });
        it("should return password should have at least one digit", () => {
          expect(function () {
            passwordIsValid("P@ss words");
          }).toThrow(errorMessages["digit "]());
        });
        it("should return password should have at least one special character", () => {
          expect(function () {
            passwordIsValid("Pas5 Words");
          }).toThrow(errorMessages["special character"]());
        });
        it("should return password should have at least one whitespace character", () => {
          expect(function () {
            passwordIsValid("p@s5Words");
          }).toThrow(errorMessages["whitespace character"]());
        });
      });
    });
```

The tests fail because the wrong error gets thrown, I can't figure out why the wrong error is being thrown:

"expected 'password should contain at least one whitespace character' to be thrown, 'password should contain at least one uppercase letter' was thrown instead"

There is a second function that imports the same helper functions being affected as well.

```
    function passwordStrength(password) {
      const strength = ["weak", "medium", "strong"];
      let strengthValue = -1;
      if (password.length < 9) {
        return "invalid";
      }
      errorMessages.errorRegex().map((condition) => {
        if (condition.test(password)) {
          strengthValue++;
        }
      });
      return strength[strengthValue > 2 ? 2 : strengthValue > 0 ? 1 : 0];
    }
```

The tests for the second function are being affected by the other functions tests

```
    describe("passwordChecker.js", () => {
      describe("passwordStrength", () => {
        it("should return invalid if condition 1 or 2 are not met", () => {
          expect(passwordStrength("p@s5word")).toBe("invalid");
        });
        it("should return weak if 3 conditions are met", () => {
          expect(passwordStrength("passwords")).toBe("weak");
        });
        it("should return medium if 4 or 5 conditions are met", () => {
          expect(passwordStrength("PassWords")).toBe("medium");
        });
        it("should return strong if 6 or more conditions are met", () => {
          expect(passwordStrength("P@s5 Words")).toBe("strong");
        });
      });
    });
```

"expected weak to be medium"

Comment: I seem to remember that regex.test is stateful, but I can't find evidence of that

Comment: Your code depends on the order of properties examined in a `for ... in` loop being consistent. That is generally true in modern JavaScript, but it's consistent in a way controlled by the runtime. It is a fragile way of doing things. If you want the tests to be made in a particular order, the test names should be in an array and your code should iterate through that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test they are stateful.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yea definitely the "g" flags are probably wrong

Comment: As an aside, it's a good idea to keep your objects consistent and single-purpose. `errorMessages` has some strings and some functions and is used in different places to do different things. The abstractions feel a bit forced here.

Comment: Thanks so much,  it definitely was the g flags carrying state through each test :p